# Need to call StreamWriter.Flush() to write the character into the file?

Tags: c#, io

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Test {
    static void Main() {
    byte[] a = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
    FileStream fileByte = new FileStream("fileByte.txt", FileMode.Create);
    fileByte.Write(a, 0, 4);

    StreamWriter fileChar = new StreamWriter("fileChar.txt");
    fileChar.Write("test");
    fileChar.Flush();


    BinaryWriter fileBin = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("fileBin.txt", FileMode.Create));
    fileBin.Write('A');

     }
}
```

Hi, I wrote these codes to get myself familiar with the I/O in C#. And I found that I have to add fileChar.Flush() to write the characters into the file. But it is not necessary to call the corresponding Flush() for either FileStream or BinaryWriter in order to put the data into the file. Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

The `Stream` object that is underlying to all your Writers/Readers buffers input until either of the follwoing happens:

- `Flush()` is called.
- The Stream's `AutoFlush` property is set to true
- The Stream is disposed.

You can use the `using` keyword to handle that for you like the following:

```
using(StreamWriter fileChar = new StreamWriter("fileChar.txt"))
{
    fileChar.Write("test");
}
```

That way, the `StreamWriter` is disposed of at the end of the block and the buffer will be written.

Comment: whenever IDisposable is implemented it is best practice in my opinion to use the "using pattern"

Comment: @Dom84, I agree. Especially `Stream` objects tend to act in unexpected ways when you do funny stuff with them, so the best thing is to use them as a data pipe and nothing more. Use the `using` keyword and if that isn't working for you, think about your program logic because likely then the `Stream` can mess up your data.

Answer (score 1):

Flushing the stream will not flush its underlying encoder unless you explicitly call Flush or Close. Setting [AutoFlush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush(v=vs.110).aspx) to true means that data will be flushed from the buffer to the stream after each write operation, but the encoder state will not be flushed. This allows the encoder to keep its state

Comment: There is a word to be said about wrapping streams with `using` statement thus calling `Close` implicitly

Answer (score 0):

Every stream related class has some form of buffering, which is basically an implementation detail.

You can see the StreamWriter.AutoFlush property ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to configure if a flush is needed or not.
For the other classes it's not, basically because they are programmed in the way they are...

I would like to point out you should always close your streams before program exits.
Try using the `using` statement, in order to guarantee the streams are properly disposed, and flushed, for you.